# sqldatasouce parameter with equal to or greaterhan

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have what seem to be simple but is in fact nearly impossible problem

I have a datagrid and sqldatasource.

If I want to select all contacts > 1 then I can use a parameter as follows:

Select * from Contacts where ContactID > @Contact
I actually want to select 3 possible values from a dopdown box:

> 1 
= 0 
>= 0

You do not seem able to alter the > = or >= in the sql statement or dropdown box which demands to be an integer value.

I cant work out how to do this. Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify the SQL statement of the SqlDataSource to achieve this, then re-bind the data in your DataGrid. You can do this by handling the `SelectedIndexChanged` method on your DropDown and `AutoPostBack="true"` or using a button.

Say your markup looks similar to the following (remove the OnSelectedIndexChanged and AutoPostBack attributes or the button as desired):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="dsContacts" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE ContactID > @Contact" />
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dgContacts" DataSourceID="dsContacts" />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlWhereOptions" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlWhereOptions_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="> 1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="= 0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text=">= 0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnChangeQuery" OnClick="btnChangeQuery_Click" />
```

And then your code-behind could look something like this:

```
Protected Sub ddlWhereOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlWhereOptions.SelectedIndexChanged 'add handles clause just in case eventwireup is false

    ChangeQuery()    

End Sub

Protected Sub btnChangeQuery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChangeQuery.Click 'add handles clause just in case eventwireup is false

    ChangeQuery()    

End Sub

Private Sub ChangeQuery()

    'set up some variables instead of building a new string in every case
    Dim whereOperator As String = ""
    Dim whereValue As Integer = 0

    Select Case ddlWhereOptions.SelectedItem.Text

        Case "> 1"
            whereOperator = ">"
            whereValue = 1

        Case "= 0"
            whereOperator = "="
            whereValue = 0

        Case ">= 0"
            whereOperator = ">="
            whereValue = 0

    End Select

    'change the select command on the datasource, clear any existing parameters and add the new one with the correct value
    dsContacts.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE ContactID " & whereOperator & " @Contact"
    dsContacts.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear()
    dsContacts.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", whereValue)

    're-bind the data grid
    dgContacts.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I had thought this might be the answer - I thought there might be a "neater" solution

Comment: Unfortunately you can't pass SQL in via a parameter, they're specifically designed to prevent SQL injection attacks, so you have to build your SQL manually, sorry!